# Writing a SQL select statement to calculate commission paid to sales employees fro the month of December

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a select statement that combines information from two tables `employee` and `invoice`. The idea is to calculate each employee's commissions earned from each invoice, select only the invoices with dates in the month of December, then combine each employee's earnings together in a single line showing that employee's total earned commission for the month.

I have zero programming experience, so I am doing this all by trial and error. I am assuming I need to insert an "SUM" function and a. "Group by statement, but every interaction I have tried has failed.  This is also working with tables I had to build using SQL commands.

This is the last thing I tried:

```
select 
    emp_lname, sum(comm_rate * inv_amount as comm_earned), inv_date
from
    employee 
join
    invoice on invoice.emp_num = employee.emp_num 
            and inv_date between '1-Dec-2018' and '31-Dec-2018' 
group by 
    emp_lname;

select 
    emp_lname, sum(comm_rate * inv_amount as comm_earned), inv_date
from 
    employee
                                         *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
select 
    emp_lname, comm_rate * inv_amount as comm_earned, inv_date
from 
    employee 
join
    invoice on invoice.emp_num = employee.emp_num 
            and inv_date between '1-Dec-2018' and '31-Dec-2018';

EMP_LNAME   COMM_EARNED     INV_DATE
--------------- ----------- ---------
Miller           2000       17-DEC-18
Miller          12500       08-DEC-18
Bernard          3600       28-DEC-18
Bernard         15000       10-DEC-18
Freeman          5000       14-DEC-18
Freeman          4000       07-DEC-18

6 rows selected.
```

I am working in an oracle database and would like to get the result down to one total comm_earned for each employee

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try this version:

```
select e.emp_lname,
       sum(e.comm_rate * i.inv_amount) as comm_earned
from employee e join
     invoice i
     on i.emp_num = e.emp_num and 
        i.inv_date >= date '2018-12-01' and
        i.inv_date <  date '2019-01-01'
group by e.emp_num, e.emp_lname;
```

Notes:

- Your first query had a misplaced parentheses in the `SELECT`.
- I included `emp_num` in the `GROUP BY` just in case two employees have the name name.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify *all* column names with the appropriate alias.
- Oracle supports the `DATE` keyword for introducing date constants using ISO-standard, unambiguous, non-locale-specific formats.
- Don't use `BETWEEN` on dates.  Time components can cause the code to do things you don't expect.  The above logic works with or without time components.